# specifying size of a 2d array in python numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I would like to statically initialize the size of an N by N 2d array in python's numpy where N is a variable (from a SQL query). The equivalent Java would be:

```
N = code from sql query
int[][] mat = new int[N][N]
```

How would I do this in numpy? Or what about a Matrix type?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a number of ways, but to create an empty array that you will later fill, you might consider:

```
N = 100
mat = np.empty((N,N))
```

There are a large number of other methods detailed in the docs:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.array-creation.html

Comment: What is a convenient way to look into the docs? From the interpreter I typed help(numpy) and it kept on spitting out documentation... I eventually had to give the terminate signal...

Comment: I would recommend using the IPython interpreter that allows you to do something like `np.empty?` which will give you that method's specific docs (http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/tutorial.html#exploring-your-objects)